# Find size of maximum clique of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In Oxy plane, given 5000 points and their coordinate (x; y) (0 < x, y < 200). There is an edge between 2 points if distance between them is not smaller than 2. Find the maximum clique of the graph. (The maximum size of a complete sub-graph of the graph)

The time limit is 1 second. So I think O(n^2) time complexity will be accepted. 
But I can't find any approach in O(n^2). This is the best algorithm I can find. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximal-clique-problem-recursive-solution/

I think there is something wrong with the algorithms on Wikipedia.
How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: There is a difference between maximal clique and maximum clique.  Maximal means that it cannot be extended to a larger clique by adding nodes.  Maximum means it has the largest possible number of nodes.  Maximum is much harder than maximal.

Comment: Oh now I just know that maximal clique is different from maximum clique

Answer (score 1):

Your graph is the complementary graph of a unit disk graph. Searching a clique in the complementary graph is searching an independent set in the unit disk graph. This is known to be NP-hard, even using the fact that the graph is a unit disk graph. So there is no polynomial algorithm known to this day. However, in the context of a unit disk graph, there exists Polynomial Time Approximation Scheme (PTAS) which can give you a good enough solution in polynomial time.
See Erlebach, T. and J. Fiala. “The Maximum Independent Set Problem in Unit Disk Graphs.” (2003) for a little introduction.